# Cannot cast list iterator to an object

Tags: c++

I get the error:

```
error C2682: cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'UserBean *'
```

When executing:

```
list<UserBean> * userBeans = getUserBeans();

for(list<UserBean>::iterator i = userBeans->begin(); i != userBeans->end(); i++)
   UserBean * newUser = dynamic_cast<UserBean*>(i);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or can you not convert iterator items to objects?

Comment: Well in java it will be. UserBean user = (UserBean) iterator.next() ; something similar perhaps in C++  as well !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes iterators are implemented as raw pointers to container items, but more times than not, they are not pointers at all, so don't treat them that way.  The **correct** way to access the item that an iterator refers to is to dereference the iterator, eg:

```
UserBean &newUser = *i;
```

Or:

```
UserBean *newUser = &(*i);
```

Iterators usually override the `->` operator so you can access members of the referenced item, in cases where the iterator refers to an actual object instance (which yours does) and not a pointer to an object instance, eg:

```
i->SomeMemberHere
```

Answer (score 5):

> Am I doing something wrong, or can you not convert iterator items to objects?

No, you can't. You can dereference iterators to access objects:

```
UserBean & newUser = *i;
```

Comment: Yes, better to use a `UserBean&` here than a `UserBean*` since this only refers to one object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert an iterator to a pointer like this - that's not what `dynamic_cast` is for. You should only be using `dynamic_cast` when you're dealing with polymorphic behaviour (if at all). You can, however, do it like so:

```
UserBean* newUser = &*i;
```

This dereferences the iterator to get the object and then takes the address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The type of your container is `list<UserBean>` not `list<*UserBean>`

That's why your iterator is wrong. Its type is `UserBean`. Not `UserBean*`.

```
UserBean userBean = *i;
```

or

```
UserBean& userBean = *i;
```

Comment: Even if the list did contain pointers (which is probably shouldn't), you'll still need to dereference the iterator rather than doing some weird cast.

Comment: "The typoe of your container" -- love it!

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Sorry, I wrote the comment before you added the part about dereferencing. But the rest of my comment stands - pointer and containers rarely mix well.

Comment: But why do you say that ? I have used containers of pointers for years in C++ ? His list is not a list of pointers, it is a list of objects ! ! !

Comment: Oh you mean if ever the OP uses polymorphism with UserBean, and then he would be victim of object slicing... So you meant "Containers and Objects" rarely mix well. Is that it ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: I read you answer as a suggestion to put pointers rather than objects in the list; and (raw) pointers in lists are a bad idea unless you've got some other data structure to manage the objects themselves. Sorry if that's not what you meant.

Comment: You're stranger and stranger. Do you have any references for saying that raw pointers in lists are bad idea.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I mean it is even obliged to use containers of pointers when one must implements polymorphism for the contained items. The containers don't accept references. What are you telling me ? Plz ? I don't catch a line ? I even strongly disagree.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: I'm rather regretting making my comment now. I merely interpreted your answer (perhaps incorrectly) as suggesting that, in this particular case, this particular list should be changed to contain pointers. That would be a bad idea since there's no polymorphism and so no need for the extra hassle of dealing with storing pointers and safely managing the pointed-to objects. A full discussion of when to store objects, raw pointers, or smart pointers is beyond the scope of this question; but one should generally avoid raw pointers since they make it harder to avoid memory leaks..

Comment: okay... it's all clear now ;-). I agree without polymorphism, rarely worth the trouble, but it has to be discussed when etc... etc...